# What kind of dashboard should i need to create wherein people can get the inferences easily

Tags: r, dashboard

Below is the data, separated by space ( more than 1 lacs rows). I tried to create a visual dashboard for the below 2 queries but the inferences are not clear, need your help to create a visual dashboard for these. Please help!

1. Distribution of client age as of their first transaction date
2. Distribution of client age by gender from their first transaction date

---

Data:

```
account_id" "client_id" "birth_number" "gender" "Trans_date"
3886 86 1969-07-20 "Female" 1994-02-20 05:30:00
3886 4643 1969-07-21 "Female" 1994-02-20 05:30:00
3886 3893 1969-12-26 "Male" 1994-02-20 05:30:00
3886 2846 1969-03-17 "Female" 1994-02-20 05:30:00
3886 2293 1969-11-22 "Male" 1994-02-20 05:30:00
3886 11874 1969-01-19 "Male" 1994-02-20 05:30:00
3886 22 1969-10-11 "Female" 1994-02-20 05:30:00
3886 3966 1969-10-07 "Female" 1994-02-20 05:30:00
3886 12802 1969-08-12 "Male" 1994-02-20 05:30:00
943 86 1969-07-20 "Female" 1993-02-03 05:30:00
943 4643 1969-07-21 "Female" 1993-02-03 05:30:00
943 3893 1969-12-26 "Male" 1993-02-03 05:30:00
2934 86 1969-07-20 "Female" 1996-10-08 05:30:00
2934 4643 1969-07-21 "Female" 1996-10-08 05:30:00
2934 3893 1969-12-26 "Male" 1996-10-08 05:30:00
2934 2846 1969-03-17 "Female" 1996-10-08 05:30:00
3759 3966 1969-10-07 "Female" 1993-12-29 05:30:00
3759 12802 1969-08-12 "Male" 1993-12-29 05:30:00
9403 86 1969-07-20 "Female" 1993-03-27 05:30:00
9403 4643 1969-07-21 "Female" 1993-03-27 05:30:00
9403 3893 1969-12-26 "Male" 1993-03-27 05:30:00
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the inferences"?

Comment: If I use geom_line the whole dashboard became a blur... not able to identify which line goes where. With bar and histogram the data is not appearing in a full manner.  Need help to know which visual dashboard is suitable for the mentioned 2 question.

Comment: Oh, so you're asking about how to graph your data. This question doesn't have anything to do with `shiny` or an online dashboard. It's actually a `ggplot` and visual design question, right?